# Overloaded method signatures - compiler see nullable types as synynomous to regular value type

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, nullable

We have a library with many methods that are overloaded with the method signature changing from value type to nullable value type as you see below:

A.) `IsEmpty(int obj, int defaultValue)`

B.) `IsEmpty(int? obj, int defaultValue)`

As you can see the only difference is that B is nullable. On most workstations in my office, this overloading compiles and the types are recognized as truly distinct.

However, for some reason, all of my machines and VMs will not compile. We are currently baffled as to why this is happening. The machines I am using should be near mirror images of other machines that are working/compiling.

**Here is a sample of the error that ensues during compilation:**

> - Error  28  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'BayTech.Common.Fix.IfEmpty(System.Guid, System.Guid)' and
>     'BayTech.Common.Fix.IfEmpty(System.Guid,
>     System.Guid?)'    C:\Projects\Applications\JukeWeb\BayTech\Internal\Common
>     Library\VS2010\Apps\BayTech.Common\Conversion\Fix.Empty.SL.cs 55  17  BayTech.Common
> - Error  11  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'BayTech.Common.Fix.IfEmpty(System.DateTime,
>     System.DateTime)' and 'BayTech.Common.Fix.IfEmpty(System.DateTime,
>     System.DateTime?)'    C:\Projects\Applications\JukeWeb\BayTech\Internal\Common
>     Library\VS2010\Apps\BayTech.Common\Conversion\Fix.Empty.SL.cs 35  17  BayTech.Common
> - Error  165 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'BayTech.Common.Fix.IfEmpty(string, System.Guid)' and
>     'BayTech.Common.Fix.IfEmpty(string,
>     System.Guid?)'    C:\Projects\Applications\JukeWeb\BayTech\Internal\Common
>     Library\VS2010\Apps\BayTech.Common\Conversion\Fix.IfEmpty.Xml.cs  259 17  BayTech.Common

Does anyone have an idea why this would be happening?

**Here's some information on the environment setup:**

- VS2010
- Idealblade (most recent install)
- Telerik controls installed including Just-In-Code
- All services packs included for VS and Windows 7
- All services packs included for VS and Windows 7
- Win7 Ultimate
- SQL 2008 R2
- VSExtensions for T4 templates, PostSharp,
- Codesmith Professional installed
- VisualSVN installed
- DevExpress
- SQLComplete installed

Comment: What the point of "IsEmpty(int obj, int defaultValue)" ?

Comment: Note that nullable types are also value types.

Comment: The overloads in the error messages are not the overloads that you posted in code. Why? Can you post consistent information?

Comment: The same library is on various machines, but is the code using the library (it's the caller that doesn't compile) the same on all machines? And what does the call look like that's not compiling?

Comment: a) some information about the call sites would be good b) there are implicit conversions between a non-nullable struct and a nullable struct, so that's why the compiler is telling you it's ambiguous, this is by design and c) your method design is flawed, if the meaning of a non null value in the method that takes a nullable is the same as the value in the non nullable method, there's no need for an overload, just use a default value for the parameter of null, or create a *true* overload with one less parameter and delegate to an private method with a different name.

Comment: You would probably get more help if you accepted answers for some of your previous questions.

Comment: Probably a target framework issue, though you've been very inconsistent in your posted information so it's hard to tell...

What are the differences between the workstations that this works on and doesn't work on?

Comment: I don't think this will work, if you pass a valid integer to this method how the compiler will know which method to call?

Comment: And why do you need this? Why not just have one method with and one without 2nd argument.

Comment: The consistency is that this is happening for all value types so thats why i didnt use the same type as I have over 400 errors from all types.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that this is not my code and its working for everyone at the company but me. So I am just looking to solve the issue or figure out why its happening. I figured it might be because they are both value types but i wonder why its just my machine that cant compile...

Answer (score -2):

There's no reason for such an implementation.
use the builtin language functionality and keep only the nullable implementation if you expect or want to handle such case. Nullable types have properties such .hasvalue or .defaultValue.